# Should this question about list of references go on the main sci-fi and fantasy site?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I looked around the other SE sites and found maybe one other SE site that this question could fall under (Literature), but the help section from both of these sites don't say whether or not its on or off topic, and what they do say seems to blur the line around where this question falls. I might just be misinterpreting things, but please help.

The question I'm trying to ask is about a list of references to time travel, whether the reference is in a movie, book, or 20 page report. I'd like to make the question a community wiki, but the problem I'm running into right now is where to put it.

What site should it be put on?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_travel_works_of_fiction

Comment: Even with a one-line entry you would very rapidly run out of space in an answer box. There are more than 2000 films listed on IMDB [containing time travel](https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=time-travel&ref_=fn_kw_kw_1). There are probably a thousand times as many books, short stories and comics that contain reference to it

Comment: A list question like this wouldn't be on-topic for *either* [scifi.se] or [literature.se], sorry. (I'm a moderator on both.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List of references for time travel? That’s not really what SE sites in general are designed for. It sounds like something that would be better suited for Wikipedia or TV Tropes or...

To be specific though if this was to be asked on the main site here it is likely to be closed under “Needs more focus” or “lists of works”. These types of questions just don’t fit with the SE question and answer site format. I wouldn’t even say this is appropriate on meta itself here.

If I were you I’d manage a Google doc or fandom site or add this onto an existing resource like Wikipedia.

Comment: There's already a Wikipedia page for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_travel_works_of_fiction I can't say how comprehensive it is, though.